# Twig is unable to find the template even though it exists

Tags: php, twig

This is my `config.php` file located in root directory of my site:

```
<?php

    define('SITE_ROOT',  dirname(__FILE__));
    define('CORE_DIR',   SITE_ROOT . '/core');
    define('VIEWS_DIR',  SITE_ROOT . '/views');
    define('ASSETS_DIR', SITE_ROOT . '/assets');

    require SITE_ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    require CORE_DIR . '/DBConnector.php';

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(VIEWS_DIR);
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

    function loadHead($title) {

        global $twig;

        echo $twig->render(VIEWS_DIR . '/head.html', array('naslov' => $title));

    }
```

`SITE_ROOT` is `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site_name` where `config.php` is located too and `head.html` is located in `views` folder.

[image]

However, I'm still getting error whenever I try to access any page in site root directory.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site_name/views/head.html" (looked into: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site_name/views).
```

So far, I tried to restart Apache server, checked directory two times to ensure that file is **actually** there (it is and I can access it directly via browser), checked folder permissions and cleared the cache but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twig locates template relative to the passed view(s) folder, in your case you set the folder to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site_name/views`, meaning the correct code to render head would be

`$twig->render('head.html', ...);`

Comment: Saved me plethora of time.